# Can I create a user without specifying a login name

Tags: linux, user-accounts, centos-6

Can I create a user without specifying a login name, and let GID used for it's login name?
I read the `man useradd(8)`, but this command seems to require a login name be set.

Any GUI way or script workaround would be appreciated.

My box is CentOS 6.4.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Why not just use the GID as the user name? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No it's not possible but you can hide the username at GDM (GNOME Display Manager)...

Comment: Hi! Keltari. Thanks for correcting my silly english mistakes.

Comment: But I did ment "CUI" way. not a GUI like involving GNOME.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible to create a user without providing a username.

Comment: As above. If you think about it, it does not make sense how can you create a user without a username. Imagine having a nameless person. The closest thing to have a blank username is actually to have a "space" as a username.. assuming the OS is willing to accept that... (and to be honest, I really doubt they will accept that)